# BAKE SOUND TO F CURVE option MISSING in blender 2.82?

Tags: fcurves

My option under KEY in the dope sheet is missing the option to bake sound to f curves.

Tried it on several scaling options on several objects but the option is totally missing.

Is there a trick to enable the feature? I dont ever remember having to do anything special before?

any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else; They moved the option from "Key" to "Channel". You should find it under there

[image]

Comment: You can also search for it using F3

Answer (score 0):

All good. It can only be done using the graph editor! Sorry fam.. its been a while since ive needed to use the function.

Comment: It has always only been available via the graph editor. Consider deleting answer & question.