How to control bones with audio?
Is there a way to control bones from a rig with audio (F-Curves) ?
I don´t find a single tutorial (or answer) to that unfortunately...

Do you know how to use audio volume to animate a value in general?

I would have asked the same as @TheLabCat here, because actually there are many tutorials how to use audio to animate F-curves, maybe not for bones, but for the method in general it doesn't matter if you animate the F-curve of a bone or any other F-curves.

nevermind.. found out it´s really easy with the graph editor :)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/169992/107598
